# How to insert image URL into table in database?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

So I'm trying to upload photos via cloudinary and insert the photo url into my table in my database so they'll save to the page. I have my route set up like so and it isn't crashing my server but it isn't inserting into my table. Any ideas? Is this a syntax error or am I not referring to the correct paths?

```
app.post('/', isLoggedIn, uploads.single('inputFile'), (req, res) => {
  console.log('On POST route');
  // get an input from user
  let file = req.file.path;
  console.log(file);
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    db.post.create({
          caption: req.body.title,
          image_url: result.url,
          user_id: req.body.user
        })
    // Render result page with image
    res.render('profile', { image: result.url });
  })
})
```

Comment: `db.post.create` is async and if you wish to do `res.render` only after a record was inserted then use `then`.

Comment: So like
`.then(res.render('profile', { image: result.url }));`
?

Comment: Almost. `.then((post) => res.render('profile', { image: result.url }));`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.post.create` is async and if you wish to call `res.render` only after a record was inserted then use `then` like this:

```js
db.post.create({
  caption: req.body.title,
  image_url: result.url,
  user_id: req.body.user
}).then((post) => res.render('profile', { image: result.url }));
```